# AllenNLP: HEAD request failed for url with status code 404 - open information extraction

Tags: allennlp

Running the training command from [open information extraction demo](https://demo.allennlp.org/open-information-extraction) fails with the following error message:

```
OSError: HEAD request failed for url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allenai/allennlp-models/main/training_config/structured-prediction/srl.jsonnet with status code 404
```

Does this mean the file is removed? Where can the replacement file be found?

Looking for a replacement file I found [this file](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/main/allennlp_models/modelcards/structured-prediction-srl.json)  from allenai repo but it seems to have required fields such as "dataset_reader" missing.

Comment: File is gone. I'd recommend leaving an issue on the repo allenai/allennlp-models.

Comment: There is no issue tab in that repo. I am assuming it has been disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

communicated the issue with allennlp and the file is now accessible at the same address.